# ¿Por qué era común que, en algunos lugares, todos se llamaran o María o José y se los llamara por el segundo nombre?

Tags: historia, nombres-propios, hispanoamérica, religión

Noté la norma leyendo sobre Alta California. Las mujeres se llamaban María de los Ángeles, María Candida, María Ramona, etc., y los hombres, José Mariano, José Antonio, José Rafael, etc. Resulta algo raro cuando a alguien se lo llama por uno de aquellos nombres, porque es poco claro.

La costumbre provino, de alguna forma, de la fe católica del pueblo. ¿Dónde y cuándo se ha usado? ¿Siempre fue solamente con estos dos nombres?

Más allá, ¿eso tiene algo que ver con las famosas combinaciones de géneros, María José y José María?

Comment: Posiblemente sea una pregunta más de cultura hispana que del lenguaje en sí. María y José eran los padres de Jesús, por lo que sus nombres son ampliamente usados en países de habla hispana. En algunos sitios incluso es inconcebible ponerle a una niña (con los niños son más laxos) un nombre que no lleve un "María" delante. Yo mismo (soy de España) tengo una prima a la que, según cuentan, el cura casi no la bautiza por querer los padres llamarla "Carmen" y no "María del Carmen".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is not related to Spanish Language, but to Spanish culture

Comment: Why is there a nombres-propios tag if given names are off-topic?

Comment: @AaronBrick browsing through the tag [nombres-propios](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nombres-propios) you can find useful cases: transliterations, origins of names, diminutives...

Comment: Iba a citar el artículo de wp de Spanish naming customs, pero no responde en más profundidad sobre los orígenes, y -lo que es más grave- no cita fuentes.